# QCA Crash on Symbian Device

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, encryption

I am using QCA and i have build the Library for Symbian 4.6.3 Debug and release mode

When i implement the code in Symbian Qt Project and Launch in Nokia C7. The app will crash when it run “Cipher”

**Run below 3 lines still no problem**

```
QCA::Initializer init = QCA::Initializer();
QCA::SymmetricKey key = QCA::SymmetricKey(QCA::hexToArray("57083063127EB2"));
QCA::InitializationVector iv = QCA::InitializationVector(QCA::hexToArray("A795271106E34"));
```

**Will Crash once run below line**

```
QCA::Cipher cipher = QCA::Cipher(QString("aes256"), QCA::Cipher::CBC,QCA::Cipher::DefaultPadding, QCA::Encode,key, iv);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: No Plugin installed.